# Parallels Desktop lock mouse in view

Tags: mac, parallels

I got an external monitor plugged into my iMac. I use parallel desktop on that monitor and when I set it to fullscreen it correctly fills the screen with the parallel desktop view. It's also generaly handy I can move the mouse between my Mac and Windows (Parallel Desktop). But when I start my game (such as League of Legends) it uses the boundries of my screen the move around, but it now ignores one side since the mouse will then enters the second monitor.This is extremely annoying. One solution would be to plug out my external monitor but I don't want. So my question:

How can I lock the mouse within the Parallels Desktop view?

Answer (score 1):

Parallels offers a configuration option named "Smart Mouse" which lets you choose whether you want to click-to-lock and hotkey-to-release or the smart auto-lock-and-release behaviour that you're having right now. I've found the matching manual page at http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v5/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/26827.htm. This is for Parallels Workstation 5 but might be available in earlier or later versions as well.